# Java error in my 2nd class

Tags: java, class

I have 2 classes. 1 class sets & gets a students' name, 3 test scores for a student & an average for the 3 scores. The other class has a main method to set and get this information. I'm getting an error from my IDE for the 2nd class only.

```
public class Student5th
{   /** 
     Instance variables
     Each student object will have a name and three test scores
    */
    private String name;             //Student name
    private int test1;               //Score on test 1
    private int test2;               //Score on test 2
    private int test3;               //Score on test 3

    /**
     Set a student's name
    Preconditions  -- nm is not empty
    Postconditions -- name has been set to name
    */
    public void setName (String nm)
    {
        name = nm;
    }
    /** Get a student's name
    Preconditions  -- none
    Postconditions -- returns the name 
    */    
    public String getName ()
    {
        return name;
    }
    /** Set the score on the indicated test
     Preconditions  -- 1 <= i <= 3 
                     -- 0 <= score <= 100
     Postconditions -- test i has been set to score
     */

    public void setScore (int i, int score)
    {
        if      (i == 1) test1 = score;
        else if (i == 2) test2 = score;
        else             test3 = score;
    }

    /** Get the score on the indicated test
     * Preconditions  -- none
     * Postconditions -- returns the score on test I
     * */
    public int getScore (int i)
    {
        if      (i == 1) return test1;
        else if (i == 2) return test2;
        else             return test3;
    }

    /** Compute and return a student's average
     * Preconditions  -- none
     * Postconditions -- returns the average of the test scores
     * */
    public int getAverage() {
        int average;
        average = (int) Math.round((test1 + test2 + test3) / 3.0);
        return average;
    }
}
```

My 2nd class with the main method...

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestStudent
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        private Student **student1**;
        private Student **student2**;
        String s;
        int t;

        student1 = new Student();
            student2 = new Student();

        s = console.next();
        student1.setName (s);
        t = console.nextInt();
            student1.setScore (1, t);
            student1.setScore (2, console.nextInt());
            student1.setScore (3, console.nextInt());

        student2.setName (**keyboard**.readLine());
            student2.setScore (1, console.nextInt());
            student2.setScore (2, console.nextInt());
            student2.setScore (3, console.nextInt());
    }
}
```

I've bolded (well, put double asterisks around) the parts which are giving me errors. I'm close to getting this program to work, but I don't know why my IDE is giving me problems for student1 & student2 in the 2nd class, as well as giving me a problem for (keyboard.readLine()); for student2.setName in the 2nd class?

Comment: Can't see the bolded parts. Can you share the compilation error that you are getting?

Comment: what error you are getting can u paste it here?

Comment: On top of Christian's answer, change your student2 line to this: student2.setName(console.nextLine());

Comment: and what is mean of using Modifier for the same method?? just Remove Private Modifier form the main method i mean that object that you are using Student object.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't specify an access level modifier (like `private` or `public`) inside a method:

```
Student student1;  // delete 'private'
Student student2;  // delete 'private'
```

**Why?** Because if you declare a variable inside a method, it should only be visible inside that specific method. It doesn't make sense to declare it as `private`, `public` or `protected`.

You could take a look to this article about [*Information hiding*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding).

Comment: Yes! Also, I needed to change keyboard to console. I can't believe my "Lecturer" said I had to make those private. Unbelievable. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe he referred to make them `private` somewhere else.

Comment: He could have meant outside of main, but still inside your TestStudent class.

Comment: @LisaSmith well my "Lecturer" use to teach me Hello World only all time. hehehe. :P

Comment: Basically, you're saying that if I make private variables in my class with the main method, I can't call methods on them from the other class? Correct?

Comment: @ Christian. I wish that were true, but I showed him my code & he literally said to make those 2 variables private. Basically, he was wrong?

Comment: No, you can do it. From [Java Tutorial](): *"Access level modifiers determine whether other classes can use a particular field or invoke a particular method.*" This means that if you declare the students objects `private` inside the class with the `main` method, those objects won't be accessible from other classes. You can still calling methods from the class `Student`, unless they were declared as `private`.

Comment: I'm not up to that level yet sadly. I will read over that soon. From what I can see, if I follow what he told me; it doesn't work.

Comment: Tell your "lecturer" to explain these concepts to you. But read about that before you ask him, so you can "debate" with him.

Comment: "debate"... really? If I hadn't used YouTube, I'd know practically nothing instead of barely anything that I do now. He's god awful. I destroy my Math Courses; but there's basically no teaching when it comes to my Java Course.

Comment: Well, that's my case too. My university courses are very basic. I've learned everything I know by myself and thanks of the Internet. Everything is on Internet. It's up to you to learn.

Comment: It should be clear that I'm already doing that. I started Java 3 weeks ago & if I was like the majority in the Course who don't look anything up; I'd be well on my way to being destroyed by basic questions on the upcoming test.

Comment: They are probably supposed to be fields, not local variables.  You've just declared them in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

A few things going on here.

- If your lecturer specified that `student1` and `student2` must be `private`, then he intended them to fields of the class.  That means you have to declare them outside of the method.  Move these two declarations up, to before the line that says `public static void main ...`.
- Also, your class is called `Student5th`, but you're using it within `TestStudent` as if it were just `Student`.  The class name used in the variable declarations has to match the actual name of the class.
- Where you wrote `keyboard.readLine()` towards the end, you actually meant to write `ccnsole.nextLine()`.  You shouldn't be trying to read the same input stream with two different objects at the same time.
- If you do change `keyboard.readLine()` to `console.nextLine()`, then you'll need an extra call to `console.nextLine()` immediately before it, to consume the newline character at the end of the line that has the first student's third score.